# Drupal Group module, add a user to a group with a particular role programmatically

Tags: drupal, module, drupal-8, drupal-modules

This question is related to **Drupal 8** **Group module**, https://www.drupal.org/project/group

I am stuck and need help with how to programmatically add a user to a group with a particular role. I am trying to assign a user to a group and role via a feed import but unable to figure out how.
To elaborate, let's say we have two groups DEV and QA. DEV is of group type A and QA is of group type B. Both groups type A & B have roles X, Y and Z (group roles). Now, I have a user $account and I want it to get added to say group QA with role Y. Can someone help and state a way I can achieve this programmatically? Code examples/snippets will be extra helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Some OLD code here that may help. Had to dig it out of git, deleted a couple of years ago as no longer needed by the project. May be deprecated!

You are loading up the group and using the $group->addMember() function. I have just added the member but you can add a second param that is an associative array that can indicate roles to add to.

```
$new_user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load($some_user_id);

// Get the group entity.
$gid = $form_state->getValue('gid');
$group = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('group')
  ->load($gid);

// Add user as a member of the group.
$group->addMember($new_user);

// Set the owner of the group to be the user.
$group->set('uid', $new_user_id);

// Save changes to group. Anything below here should only be changes to
// Group Content.
$group->save();
$tags = $group->getCacheTagsToInvalidate();
Cache::invalidateTags($tags);
```

Comment: Thankyou for the response.
However, assigning a role is the place where am facing the challenge. Right now, I have something like this, 

$values = ['group_roles' => 'Y'];
$group->addMember($account, $values);

However, the user is getting added to the group but the role is not. Just getting added as an anonymous user.

Comment: Had a look in the DB and figured it out,
$values = ['group_roles' => $groupType . '-' . $roleName];
$group->addMember($account, $values);

This works like a charm!